# strace -f on own recursive c++ program won't work

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls, strace

so I have a simple recursive c++ program, very basic:

```
#include <iostream>

int fibonacciRec(int no) {
    if (no == 0 || no == 1)
        return no;
    else
        return fibonacciRec(no-1) + fibonacciRec(no-2);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int no = 42;
    for (int i = 1; i <= no; i++) {
        std::cout << fibonacciRec(i-1) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to run `strace` on this program, showing all the system calls. Basically I want to see a lot of mmaps etc. but as soon, as the first loop is called, `strace -f` stops following the system calls and only shows the last `write` call. Also `strace -c` gives unlikely numbers, since the program takes well more then 4-6 seconds to compute:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
60.47    0.000078          78         1           munmap
26.36    0.000034          11         3           brk
13.18    0.000017           3         6           fstat
 0.00    0.000000           0         4           read
 0.00    0.000000           0         1           write
 0.00    0.000000           0         5           close
 0.00    0.000000           0        14           mmap
 0.00    0.000000           0        10           mprotect
 0.00    0.000000           0         6         6 access
 0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
 0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
 0.00    0.000000           0         5           openat
 ------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 100.00    0.000129                    57         6 total
```

Comment: The `strace -c` output only show the time in *system calls*, not the time of the rest of your program. If you want the time of non-system calls then perhaps use a *profiler*?

Comment: As for the `strace -f` problem, if you lower the limit of the loop (i..e a much smaller value for `no`) then perhaps the `strace -f` output is small enough to post inside the question itself. Then it's much easier for us to know what's happening.

Comment: And lastly, please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for any mmaps or any other system calls when `fibonacciRec` is running.

The only memory that might be allocated is stack memory for the recursive calls, and there are several reasons why you those don't show up in the `strace`:

- It's really not a lot of memory. Your maximum recursion depth is about 42, and you've only got 1 local variable, so the stack frames are small. The total stack allocated during the recursion is probably less than 1 page.
- Even if it was a lot of memory, the stack allocation only grows, it never shrinks, so you'd see it grow to its maximum pretty quickly, then stay there for a long time. It wouldn't be a flood.
- Stack allocation isn't done with a system call anyway. To ask the kernel for more stack, all you have to do is pretend you already have it. The kernel catches the page fault, notices that the faulting address is near your existing stack, and allocates more. It's so transparent that even `strace` can't see it.

Apart from calling itself and returning a value, `fibonacciRec` doesn't do anything but manipulate local variables. There are no system calls.

Comment: C++ provides dynamic memory and automatic memory.  It includes a 'std::stack' container, but never (I think) a "stack", nor a "heap".   Linux has a stack, which, on Lubuntu 18.04, has default size of 8 M Bytes per thread.  I have never seen the idea that a Linux page fault can increase stack size.

Comment: @2785528 you can see it here for example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145557/how-does-stack-allocation-work-in-linux Your 8M is a limit. The stack starts small and grows on demand. If the limit is exceeded you'll get a segfault. The current stack size for a process can be found by examining `/proc/$PID/maps`

Comment: Excellent ... thank you for the reference.  You have shown me something new to investigate.  I have done experiments to grow the stack until something happened, but my experiments always forced an error (don't remember which).  I did find and confirm I could change the limit on the command line prior to running my app.

Comment: @Simon - the following site shows some possible commands for how to set a bigger ulimit for your next trial https://www.nics.tennessee.edu/faq/general-how-do-i-change-my-default-limits-stack-size-core-file-size-etc.  There is also something called a hardlimit on some hw.  I searched with "linux, how set stack limit."

Comment: Thanks everyone; i like to think  I have a little more understanding of memory organization now. Thanks wumpus.